# Laravel, Livewire and DOMPDF

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, dompdf

I have a very simple Livewire component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use PDF;
use Livewire\Component;

use App\Models\Employee;

class Employees extends Component{

public $employees;

public function mount()
{
    $this->employees = Employee::all()->toArray();
}

public function createPDF()
{
    $this->employees = Employee::all()->toArray();
    // dd($this->employees);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('livewire.employees', $this->employees);
    return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.employees');
}

}
```

and a very simple blade file where I render the names of the employees which I want to print when the button is clicked.

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
  @foreach ($employees as $e)
    <h2>{{ $e['name'] }}</h2>
  @endforeach
  <button wire:click="createPDF" class="mt-8 bg-black text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">PDF</button>
</div>
```

The problem is that I get "Undefined variable $employees" for the variable which is inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the variable in your PDF call, so the variable doesn't exist.

Simply change

```php
$pdf = PDF::loadView('livewire.employees', $this->employees);
```

to

```php
$pdf = PDF::loadView('livewire.employees', ['employees' => $this->employees]);
```

P.S. I don't quite understand why you fetch the employees each time the PDF generate button is clicked. You've already set it in the mount, so it should already be set. Re-fetching each time is pretty slow.